# Using an adjective form instead of the verb form

Tags: verbs, adjectives

> Many of the ***concepts covered*** require the reader to abandon
>   comfortable modes of thought

In the above sentence, the word "covered" is a verb. I was wondering could that sentence be rephrased like this - so that the word "covered" becomes an adjective:

> Many of the ***covered concepts*** require the reader to abandon
>   comfortable modes of thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed, you may do this.

The form with *-ed* here is called the past **participle**, which means a form which *participates* in multiple contexts: it may act as a verb AND an adjective, or as a verb AND a noun, at the same time.

And in fact in you first sentence it is also acting as an adjective. Participles are often placed *after* the nouns they modify because they may, as verbs, have complements or adjuncts which in English may not come before the noun:

> Many of the concepts [covered by this text] require the reader ... *but not*
>   <sup>✲</sup> Many of the [covered by this text] concepts require the reader ...

The starred example is not permitted in English, though it is in at least one other closely related language, German. (Note that *related* there is another adjectival participle.)

---

<sup>✲</sup> *marks a usage as unacceptable*